GridSearchCV error: ValueError: Sequential model 'sequential' has no defined outputs yet
I am trying to fine tune the hyperparameters for my deep learning neural network on a dataset which I have done feature engineering on. I have kept only relevant features and have standardized the data as well (using MinMaxScaler). I have followed the steps that I have seen online to find the best parameters:

Feature engineering/Data standardization (Pre-processing)
Making a build function of the neural network
Creating a KerasRegressor object with that neural network
Create parameters dictionary that I wish to test
Create a GridSearchCV object with the KerasRegressor object as the estimator and the param_grid as the parameters dictionary
Fitting the data using a training set (from train_test_split)
Printing best_params_

However I ran into an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 428, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 275, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 620, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 288, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 288, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py", line 127, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 732, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 760, in fit
    self._fit(
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 926, in _fit
    self._check_model_compatibility(y)
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 549, in _check_model_compatibility
    if self.n_outputs_expected_ != len(self.model_.outputs):
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 277, in outputs
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Sequential model 'sequential' has no defined outputs yet.
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vishv\OneDrive\Documents\Projects and Personal Learning\Spotify Top 200 Chart Analysis\prediction_test.py", line 100, in <module>
    grid = grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 898, in fit
    self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 1419, in _run_search
    evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 845, in evaluate_candidates
    out = parallel(
          ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py", line 65, in __call__
    return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1098, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 975, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 567, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 456, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vishv\anaconda3\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
ValueError: Sequential model 'sequential' has no defined outputs yet.

Below is my code. Note that I am fairly new to machine learning and neural nets:
# DataFrame Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random as rnd

# Visualization Libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandasgui import show
import seaborn as sns

# Machine Learning Libraries
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import R2Score
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping


# Read in Data
spotify_df = pd.read_csv('spotify_top_songs_audio_features.csv',index_col="id")

# Clean Data
    # Dropping source, mode, key, time_signature (no/little correlation to features)
spotify_df.drop(['source','mode', 'key', 'time_signature'],axis=1,inplace=True)

    # Mapping outlier in artist_names (Tyler, The Creator -> Tyler The Creator) 
def tyler_map(artist_names):
    if 'Tyler, The Creator' in artist_names:
        return artist_names.replace('Tyler, The Creator','Tyler The Creator')
    else:
        return artist_names

spotify_df['artist_names'] = spotify_df['artist_names'].apply(tyler_map)

    # Splitting artist names into lists of each artist + making dummies for each artist
spotify_df['artist_names'] = spotify_df['artist_names'].apply(lambda x:x.split(", "))

artist_dummy = pd.get_dummies(data=spotify_df['artist_names'].explode(),drop_first=True).groupby(level=0).sum()

    # Concat dummies to original list (without artist_names)
spotify_df = pd.concat([spotify_df.drop('artist_names',axis=1),artist_dummy],axis=1)

X = spotify_df.iloc[:,13:]
y = spotify_df['weeks_on_chart']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=0, patience=25)

def buildModel(optimizer='adam'):
    model = Sequential()
    

    model.add(Dense(234, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))

    for i in range(2):
        model.add(Dense(78, activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.1))

        model.add(Dense(78, activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    for i in range(5):
        model.add(Dense(39, activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.1))

        model.add(Dense(39, activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    for i in range(3):
        model.add(Dense(13, activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.1))

        model.add(Dense(13, activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='mean_absolute_error',metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

    return model

nn = KerasRegressor(model=buildModel,epochs=600,callbacks=[early_stop])

parameters = {'batch_size':[30,40,50,60,70],
              'optimizer':['adam','rmsprop','adamw']}

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=nn,param_grid=parameters,scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',cv=3)

grid = grid.fit(X_train,y_train)

print(grid.best_params_)


I'd recommend using MLPRegressor from Scikit-Learn API if you want to use GridSearchCV, as it'll be more compatible. (And maybe use RandomSearchCV if you start having a lot of hyperparameters to set).
Take also a look at the Pipeline in Scikit-Learn here.
Alternatively, you can use a framework dedicated to hyperparameters tuning like Optuna, which has good support for TensorFlow.

Thank you for the ideas. Would using MLPRegressor allow me to use my own neural network function as I created above? I am looking to optimize my batch size and optimizer for my current function.

Yes MLPRegressor allow some customization, but not as much as TensorFlow. So with it, you cannot use your function. But, you can optimize the batch size! There is an argument batch_size. To use your function, you can use Optuna as hyperparameters frameworks.

Instead on using GridSearch, I suggest you to use Keras Tuner
